# What's the difference between a condition and an expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I've seen these two words used a lot in a similar way.

Can a condition contain multiple expressions?

Comment: "_Can a condition contain multiple expressions?_" Can't you just try it and see?

Comment: Expression is anything which is evaluated to a value, statements are not evaluated to values. That means condition is an expression, and yes, you can put multiple expressions in a condition.

Comment: yes a condition can contain multiple expressions.  A condition is something that evaluates to true/false.  An expression is just a technical term for "code" really.  It could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

An expression is any piece of code you write. Typically (in most languages) a semicolon (";") indicates the end of an expression.

A condition is an expression which is either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Almost in every programming language, an expression is a compound of operators and operands, where operators can be any arithmetics, logic, equalty, and operands are any number or variable.
And for answering you question, yes it can.
An example could be

```
a = b || b = c || b = 2
```

You can take a look here for some examples and further explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators